# Octopus using(:master) on an entire model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, octopus

I'm trying to use a specific DB on a whole model. Basically, we have a master/slave DB configuration, and I want to do using(:master) on whole order-related methods (so on the whole order model).

The thing is that I can apparently do using(:master) at the top of my model, but I'm unsure about what it does and I cant find it in the doc:

- Will all the calls in the model use master (like, if a method does User.find in this model, will it use master?)
  or
- Will all the calls all across the app for the Order methods use master (like, if a method in the User model does Order.find, will it use master?)

Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we did it.
We made the master connection the same as the default database defined in the database.yml.
Then in each of the models that live in master we would put the following line right below the class line.

octopus_establish_connection Rails.env.to_sym